# Как сделать повторный ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: java

Всем привет! Подскажите как сделать повторный ввод с клавиатуры, например здесь -

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите цифру: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();

        if (n > 0 && n < 11) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    System.out.print((i + 1) * (j + 1) + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
}
```

lДопустим я ввожу некорректное значение n и мне надо чтобы программа не заканчивала свою работу, а позволила вести корректное значение n

Comment: Сделать проверку через if, и если некорректный ввод предложить ввести, ещё раз.

Comment: Добавь все выражение после создания сканера в цикл `while(true)`, тогда будет бесконечно запрашивать ввод. Чтобы выйти из цикла можно сделать какое-либо ключевое слово (в данном случае число), при вводе которого будет вызваться `break`, т.е. цикл будет благополучно завершаться

Answer (score -1):

Как по мне проще всего использовать while

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        boolean isTrue = true;

        while (isTrue){
            // Пока наше число не станет больше или меньше 0
            // раз за разом нам будет предложено ввести его заново.
        System.out.println("Введите цифру: ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n < 11) {
            isTrue = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    System.out.print((i + 1) * (j + 1) + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Давай попробуем использовать РЕКУРСИЮ. Для этого создадим статический метод, который ничего не возвращает, и поместим туда часть твоего кода.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        yourVoid();

    }

    private static void yourVoid() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите цифру: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n < 11) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    System.out.print((i + 1) * (j + 1) + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } else {
            yourVoid();
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно же в идеале нужно создать отдельный класс, в нем создать этот метод и прописать этот код, так как в класс Main обычно другие методы не добавляют, но для учебных целей можно сделать исключение.